# How to install Ubuntu version 19.10 on a external disk directly from an Ubuntu 19.10 machine without using a bootable USB drive?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, ssd

I have an Ubuntu 19.10 system on my main PC.

I have installed Ubuntu or other Linux distros various times in the past and I am pretty accustomed to the instalation process.

I am wondering if it is possible or there is an official software or any other tool to automatically install Ubuntu on a new external SSD without using a bootable USB drive or DVD.

Comment: Look up how to use debootstrap.

Comment: A universal method for finding more about a command is to open a terminal and type `man debootstrap` (substitute the command you want to learn more about for _debootstrap_). You can also open a web browser and search on `ubuntu man debootstrap` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/debootstrap.8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### USB or DVD easiest

- I think it is easiest to boot a live USB system from a USB pendrive or DVD disk, and run the installer from there.

### Grub-n-ISO alias ISO-boot

- 'Grub-n-ISO' is an alternative when you have an iso file with the version that you want to install in your internal drive.

  You can point to it in a file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and run

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```

  to make it active by copying the menuentry into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- See the following links to Ubuntu help pages,

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

  Example of menuentry for Ubuntu 19.10, where the ISO file is located in the `/iso` folder of the partition `/dev/sda5` alias `(hd0,5)` in grub. Modify to match *your* case.

  ```
  menuentry "Ubuntu 19.10 Desktop iso" {
     set isofile="/iso/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso"
     loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
  ```
- After rebooting you can select this new grub menuentry and boot into a live system, when you have the installer and you can install Ubuntu to your external drive.
- There are reports of a [bug with grub version 2.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1851311), that makes it difficult or impossible to use this method, but it works with grub version 2.02.

Answer (score 1):

### You Can do a Full install to USB drive from Ubuntu or Windows using Virtual Box.

From Ubuntu or Windows install VirtualBox if you do not already have it, There are lots of instructions for this elsewhere.

Start VBox and make a new Ubuntu machine.

Start the Ubuntu machine and point it at the Ubuntu iso file.

When the process gets to the Try/Install window select "Try".

Plug in your USB and confirm it is visible to VBox.

Select the Install Ubuntu icon on the desktop.

When you get to partitioning select "Something else"

Select the USB as target for the install.

Continue the installation as normal until complete.