# How to install Xubuntu from persistent USB?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, usb-installation

I have a persistent LUKS-encrypted Xubuntu installation on a bootable USB-Stick.
I can start the system on a laptop that I want to install Xubuntu on. I can use the System, but I do not have a clue how to install it to HDD.
I do not care if I do a fresh install or somehow get the running system from USB to HDD.
I only have this laptop, this one usb stick I do not want to overwrite and no further sticks or boot media.
I wish there was a "install now" shortcut like on a live system..
Any ideas? :)

Comment: You can try the Grub-n-ISO alias ISO-boot method according to [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198357/how-to-install-ubuntu-version-19-10-on-a-external-disk-directly-from-an-ubuntu-1/1198385#1198385). It should work at least if you have grub 2.02 (but there may be problems with grub 2.0.4 to boot into an iso file). There may be a problem because of the encryption if the `/boot` partition is too small for the iso file.

Comment: An installed system does NOT contain the installer application. Either look up how to use debootstrap or buy/borrow another USB stick

Comment: If you made your Full install USB, use the same method, (live DVD or Live USB), to install to your internal disk. I have asked how to do it and got no workable answers here> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165276/make-full-install-to-usb-able-to-install-ubuntu